# How to use azure file storage with Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureportal, azure-files

I have created two storage accounts, one have my azure function while another is a file storage account. What I want is to create a file from azure function and store it in my azure file storage. I went through [official](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files#develop-with-file-storage) documentation of file storage as well as of Azure function, but I am not finding any connecting link between the two.

Is it possible to create file from azure function and store it in file storage account, if yes, please assist accordingly.

Comment: You can use Azure Storage SDK to store data in a file storage account.

Comment: Thanks..but can you elaborate as exactly how to do that..The documentation is little confusing

Comment: I think it would be hard for me to explain the basic concepts of uploading file. If you read the documentation, you will find plenty examples about uploading a file in a file service share. Please follow those examples. Once you have done that and still have some questions, please update your questions with the code you have written and the problems you are running into.

Comment: I don't want to upload file manually in my file storage account. I want to create it from my azure function. Is it possible? If yes, please guide me towards that specific documentation link--I am not asking for code, I at least want a reference point to start.

Comment: Aah....If I am not mistaken, you want an output binding where the function would automatically push the data in File Storage. Am I correct?

Comment: Somewhat.. I want my azure function to create and write file in my file storage.i.e the function which automatically push the data in a _new_ file in my file storage and write data to it.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it is not supported as of today. Blob output binding is supported though.

Comment: We don't have a first class Azure Files binding. This is tracked as a feature in our repo here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues/14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a preview of [Azure Functions External File bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-external-file) to upload file to external storage, but it doesn't work with Azure File Storage. There is a [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues/14) to create a new type of binding for Files.

Meanwhile, you can upload the file just by using Azure Storage SDK directly. Something like

```cs
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File;

public static void Run(string input)
{
    var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("...");
    var fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
    var share = fileClient.GetShareReference("...");
    var rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();  
    var sampleDir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference("MyFolder");
    var fileToCreate = sampleDir.GetFileReference("output.txt");
    fileToCreate.UploadText("Hello " + input);
}
```

Comment: I couldn't manage to use azure storage sdk inside azure function. It gives the errors:
The type or namespace name 'File' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage'
Then if I comment it, it still doesn't recognizes CloudStorageAccount saying:
The type or namespace name 'CloudStorageAccount' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage'
It seems to me that the function runtime 1 and 2 (preview) doesn't allow to change the target framework and is selecting by default something that doesn't have access to storage. Or I'm just missing something :)